# Retrieve empty array from Parse error

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, parse-platform, nsarray

In my app the user can view his own statistics. I retrieve an array from Parse like this:

```
...
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    userArray = [objects valueForKey:@"myArray"];
}];
```

The code works just fine when the array actually contains something... But if nothing is saved to the array in Parse.com I get errors..

Example:
I run this code to test:

```
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[[userArray objectAtIndex:0] count]);
```

When the array contains something it logs the correct number (works). But when the array is empty I get this error:

```
"-[NSNull count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x199084fe0"
```

I can't figure out what is going on.. Anyone has an idea what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting an empty array, you are getting an `NSNull`. You can read more about the difference [here](http://nshipster.com/nil/).

Testing for NSNull is trivial. Consider replacing values that aren't NSArrays with nil.

```
id myArray = userArray.firstObject;
myArray = [myArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] ? myArray : nil;
NSLog(@"%i", [myArray count]); //will log 0 because myArray is nil
```

Comment: So what exactly is this doing? And how can it help me? I still get the same error..

Comment: Why wouldn't you just test if it is null? Like this:


    `id object = myArray[0];// similar to [myArray objectAtIndex:0]

    if(![object isEqual:[NSNull null]])
    {
        //do something if object is not equals to [NSNull null]
    }`

Comment: I guess you could do that too if you prefer having conditional blocks in your code...

Comment: Could you take a look at my own answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I found this code to help on my problem:

```
id object = userArray[0];

if([object isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
    NSLog(@"Array is empty");
}
```

Is this safe to use?

Comment: I'm obviously not as advanced as you, but I think I'll go for my solution for now.. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Also, this won't catch cases when you get something that _isn't_ an `NSNull`. Like an `NSDictionary` or something else you aren't expecting. That's why I used `isKindOfClass:` to check if it's an `NSArray`.